# nettyserver not started for Play2 in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, netty

I'm new to Intellij IDEA for Play/Scala and apparently need to do something to start NettyServer when I Run a project. My run configuration ran once OK. Then I killed the server, made some changes and tried to run again:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djline.terminal=none -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dsbt.global.base=/private/var/folders/97/16yb2phd7sz78q0sf5wl7z200000gn/T/sbt-global-pluginstub -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -classpath "/Users/j/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2016.1/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar" xsbt.boot.Boot run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jch/IdeaProjects/editor/project
[info] Set current project to ...

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[error] p.c.s.NettyServer - Failed to listen for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000!
[error] (compile:run) play.runsupport.ServerStartException
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Apr 4, 2016 11:24:31 AM

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I missing?

My Mistake. - Apparently NettyServer could not start because it was already running. When I browse to localhost:9000 it's up. A better error message would have helped, and IDEA apparently did not autoload into my browser because of the NettyServer exit code.

Comment: Can you check if the server is still running with task manager?

Comment: You should make this an answer, since it is the answer! "already running in another terminal"